# RSPAMD not sending out reports

Tags: dmarc, rspamd

Since some time our DMARC reports won't get send out.
If we do rspamadm  dmarc_report -v  -n 20230612 we see the e-mail that should be send out but if we do: rspamadm  dmarc_report -v  20230612 it tells us:

send data for 0 domains (from 1 to 0)

Config:

```
reporting {
    # Required attributes
    enabled = true; # Enable reports in general
    email = 'redacted@foo.bar'; # Source of DMARC reports
domain = 'foo.bar'; # Domain to serve
org_name = 'A foo walks into a bar'; # Organisation
# Optional parameters
bcc_addrs = ["redacted@foo.bar"]; # additional addresses to copy on reports
report_local_controller = false; # Store reports for local/controller scans (for testing only)
#helo = 'rspamd.localhost'; # Helo used in SMTP dialog
#smtp = '127.0.0.1'; # SMTP server IP
#smtp_port = 25; # SMTP server port
from_name = 'dmarc-support-acc'; # SMTP FROM
#msgid_from = 'rspamd'; # Msgid format
max_entries = 1k; # Maxiumum amount of entries per domain
keys_expire = 7d; # Expire date for Redis keys
#only_domains = '/path/to/map'; # Store reports merely from those domains
send_reports = true;
}
```

Run the DMARC report generation manually.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. Seems fixed now. Running gdb on the redis master once fixed it.. –